# implementing Moving Average function in JSP using mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans, xampp

i have a sample code for moving average that i would like to implement using data from mySQL.

data from the array below should come from database not array

```
double[] testData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

how can i implement it?

```
public class MovingAverage {

    private final Queue<Double> window = new LinkedList<Double>();

    private final int period;

    private double sum;

    public MovingAverage(int period) {

        assert period > 0 : "Period must be a positive integer";

        this.period = period;
    }

    public void newNum(double num) {

        sum += num;

        window.add(num);

        if (window.size() > period) {

            sum -= window.remove();
        }
    }

    public double getAvg() {

        if (window.isEmpty()) return 0.0; // technically the average is undefined

        return sum / window.size();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] testData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        int[] windowSizes = {3, 5};

        for (int windSize : windowSizes) {

            MovingAverage ma = new MovingAverage(windSize);

            for (double x : testData) {

                ma.newNum(x);

                System.out.println("Next number = " + x + ", SMA = " + ma.getAvg());

            }

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might it be an idea to enact the moving average in sql instead?

Comment: Take a look at [Beyond WHERE and GROUP BY](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/beyond_where_groupby/) ~p.52 (and use AVG instead of SUM). Expected output a table might be useful.

Comment: Use jdbc.......

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to get the data from a database instead of from an array?

Comment: yes,i would like to get data from database not array